# How can I configure the X-AUTH-TOKEN in the keyrock FIWARE

Tags: authentication, fiware

I want to configure the X-Auth-Token of Keyrock created by Fiware. But the thing is that the X-Auth-Token expire after an hour. And I want that the X-Auth-Token expire when the session is inactive or I want to know when can I reactive the auth-token for example when the token has 20 min left.

I don't know if I have explain well.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you can do something when you request the token. For example: when receive the token, start a countdown and trigger what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to configure the [Keystone tokens expiration here](https://github.com/ging/keystone/blob/master/etc/keystone.conf.sample#L1517).

For OAuth2 tokens, you can follow as [described here](https://ask.fiware.org/question/657/keyrock-token-duration/):

> 1) import CONF: from keystone import config CONF = config.CONF
>
> 2) add this line in "def init" of "class Server", just after the
>   comments: tokene

xpiresin=CONF.token.expiration

The second link has a reference for how to configure expiration time for keystone tokens (there is a config file in which you can set this) and some ideas about the same for OAuth2 tokens.